# Masonry type background images

Tags: css, ruby

I am doing some research for a ruby on rails web app I am working on and need some help with a few questions.

1. Is it possible to render/display images as the background of a web page using a masonry jquery type pluggin?
2. If the answer to the 1st question is no, then is is possible to manually render multiple images as a background using css(3) and html(5)?
3. Lastly, if I can use 1, 2 or any other method to display multiple background images, will I be able to apply regular css code to manipulate the images?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with CSS3. At it's most simplest, here is an example of how you would achieve it:

```
#exampleA {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background-image: url(decoration.png), url(ribbon.png), url(old_paper.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top, right bottom, left top;
}
```

The order runs from first (on the left) being the top layer to the last (on the right) being the bottom background layer (that's if you're layering them).

EDIT: In order to apply more complicated stylings to each background image such as greyscale you need to break up the CSS into this sort of format:

```
/* this is the master css block - the height and width here represent the total coverage for all child background images */
    .sample1 .sea, .sample1 .mermaid, .sample1 .fishing {
       height: 300px;
       width: 480px;
       position: relative;

    }
/* individual stylings for each background image featured - apply greyscale and separate width and heights here */
    .sample1 .sea {
       background: url(media/sea.png) repeat-x top left;
    }
    .sample1 .mermaid {
       background: url(media/mermaid.svg) repeat-x bottom left;
    }
    .sample1 .fish {
      background: url(media/fish.svg) no-repeat;
      height: 70px;
      width: 100px;
      left: 30px;
      top: 90px;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .sample1 .fishing {
      background: url(media/fishing.svg) no-repeat top right 10px;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I tried your suggestion and it works! However I have one problem, I cant see to apply sizes or grayscale to the background images. Here is the code I am using;

<style>
body
{
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
background-image: url('images/1000.jpg'), url('images/1001.jpg'), url('images/1002.jpg'), url('images/1004.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: 10px 10px, 225px 10px, 840px 10px, 1150px 10px;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
background-attachment:fixed;
float: left;
opacity: .5;
}
</style>

Comment: This is genius!!!!!!! How come I didn't think of it?! This answer should have over hundreds of votes! This should be heard! :D